# Android insert image into EditText

Tags: android

I'm trying to adding some image into EditText with below code as :

```
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(APP.DIR_APP + APP.IMAGE + "/ok.png");

Drawable mDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), myBitmap);

ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(mDrawable);

SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();

builder.append(contentText.getText());
String imgId = "[img=1]";

int selStart = contentText.getSelectionStart();
builder.replace(contentText.getSelectionStart(), contentText.getSelectionEnd(), imgId);

builder.setSpan(imageSpan, selStart, selStart + imgId.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
contentText.setText(builder);
```

this path as `APP.DIR_APP + APP.IMAGE + "/ok.png"`  is correct and i check that with `file.exists()` and that return true, but i don't have selected image into edittext

Comment: See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3704545/5550161

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not forget to call 
`mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, myBitmap.getWidth(), myBitmap.getHeight())`.
or
`mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, mDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), mDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());`

Currently you have bounds set to 0,0,0,0 -- so, you don't see your image. It's zero-sized.

You can set other bounds if you want to scale your image.

Do not forget to scale your image for different screen densities.