# How to let users put image and text in Edit Text field?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing an android application, where I have an EditText in which I want users to put message along with the image in the same EditText.how can a user be able to put images in EditText view please help.

Comment: SpannableString may help , refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/26767587/5396745

Answer (score 0):

Use [ImageSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/ImageSpan.html)

Just like SpannableStrings, you can also use ImageSpan to add to your EditText.

```
Spannable span = new SpannableString("Some text that you want to add");
Drawable android = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.sampeImage);
android.setBounds(0, 0, 32,32);
ImageSpan image = new ImageSpan(android, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
span.setSpan(image, 3, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
editTextView.setText(span);
```

Just like above you can have any drawable and add this to span. and then set this span to edit textview

Comment: How can i get text and image from the users and not from the drawable folder.

Comment: You can open gallery and allow user to select image from that. Refer this link for the same. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38352148/get-image-from-the-gallery-and-show-in-imageview

Comment: Now i got image from gallery intent but how can i set this to spannable string.

Comment: Convert bitmap to drawable and use it in above code. Drawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), bitmap);

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: Use Spannable String:

Here -> [Stack answer to Follow Along](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26767451/image-inside-edittext-android/26767587#26767587)

This one is also similar -> [Another Stack answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818438/how-to-insert-image-to-a-edittext)

--- if you want the images to be uploaded by user instead of `drawable` then you have multiple ways to allow the user upload images.. please follow along these links

[Example # 01](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9107900/how-to-upload-image-from-gallery-in-android)

[Nice tutorial here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/pick-image-from-galary-android-app/)

[Basic but useful](https://android.forums.wordpress.org/topic/upload-images-to-gallery)

if you stuck with any specific problem.. please come up with your code highlighting the area where you're stuck at..